# How to send JSON array in Spring STS for citrus?

Tags: json, spring, citrus-framework

I have to send an array like:

1.

```
"market": [ "UK" , "US" , "PK"],`
```

2.

```
"units": [{
    "id": ObjectId("59762d7caddb13b4a8440a4g"),
    "name": "unitName-1"

},{

    "id": ObjectId("59762d7caddb13b4a8440a5g"),

    "name": "unitName-2"

}]
```

I know the keyvalue pair format for sending in post/put request in Spring STS tool as follows:

```
http().client(attributeClient) //
    .post("/") //
    .payload("{ \"name\": \"attribute1\","
            + "\"description\": \"this is description\","
            + "\"market\": \"UK\","
            + "\"helpText\": \"this is helptext\","
            + "\"type\": \"text\","
            + "\"required\": \"false\","
            + "\"repeatable\": \"false\","
            + "\"readOnly\": \"false\","
            + "\"systemLevel\": \"false\","
            + "\"units\": \"false\","
            + "\"codedValues\": \"false\","
            + "\"mask\": \"XX-XX-XXXX\","
            + "\"length\": \"100\","
            + "\"industryId\": \"false\"}") //
    .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE) //
    .accept(APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
```

How to send the array as specified above?

Comment: Formatting is important. If you ask a question, make the task of the answerer so easy as you only can! Format it well, it makes them much easier (and, for you, friendlier) the decision, if they want to spend time to help you!

Comment: @asif-alam I am involved with the Citrus Framework. I'd like to help you, but I'm afraid I haven't understood your question properly. First of all, how to format you string for the `payload()` method doesn't depend on the IDE you use. It depends on Java Syntax and thus, you have to escape every `"` with a backslash `\` inside a Java String. Moreover, the examples you have put under `1` and `2` are not valid JSON strings, they miss surrounding curly braces (`{ }`). You can verify JSON strings [here](https://jsonlint.com). Could you please rephrase your question with more details?